# How can I reuse Django admin search feature?

Tags: django, search, django-admin

I'm developing an application with Django.I'm using Django admin's search feature like this:

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     search_fields = ('image_name', 'product_name', )
```

And it gives a very nice search on these columns. Now I want to use this search in my views and inside my code. I mean I want to reuse this search which Django uses for the admin page in my code.
I've read the code of ModelAdmin class but I couldn't reuse it, because it uses some objects from other layers of Django.
So I couldn't figure out how can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this. My main concern was being able to use Django admin search because it was completely identical to what I needed and not because of I wanted to adhere to the "write once" philosophy. So I read the code and copied the part which was doing the search thing. I removed some error detection parts and general purpose codes and passed the variables which it  needed to work correctly and then it worked.